# getting data from ID3D11Texture2D

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I saw some similar post but not for NV12 format, so here is my code:

```
void MyClass::loadPreviewTexture(){

ID3D11Texture2D* textureBuf;
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> tempTexture = this->c_PreviewTexture;
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC tempDesc;

if (tempTexture != nullptr){

    tempTexture->GetDesc(&tempDesc);

    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;

    ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));

    textureDesc.Width = tempDesc.Width;
    textureDesc.Height = tempDesc.Height;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = tempDesc.MipLevels;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = tempDesc.ArraySize;
    textureDesc.Format = tempDesc.Format; // NV12
    textureDesc.SampleDesc = tempDesc.SampleDesc;

    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = tempDesc.MiscFlags;

    tempTexture->GetDevice(&device);
    device->GetImmediateContext(&context);
    device->GetImmediateContext(&context);
    device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &textureBuf);

    context->CopyResource(textureBuf, tempTexture.Get());

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE  mapResource;
    HRESULT hr = context->Map(textureBuf, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, NULL, &mapResource);

    //data = new byte[(mapResource.RowPitch / sizeof(byte)) * textureDesc.Height];
    //this->size = (mapResource.RowPitch / sizeof(byte)) * textureDesc.Height;

    this->size = textureDesc.Width * textureDesc.Height * 3 * sizeof(byte);
    data = new byte[this->size];


    //memcpy(data, mapResource.pData, mapResource.RowPitch* textureDesc.Height);
    memcpy(data, mapResource.pData, this->size);
    printf("");
}
```

}

c_PreviewTexture is a ComPtr and contains the data I need.
 I'm not sure about the size of data[] and the allocation. The size for NV12 format is suppose to be 1280*720*3 for a resolution of 1280 * 720. I'm missing something because it worked if I copy like this:

```
memcpy(data, mapResource.pData, mapResource.RowPitch* textureDesc.Height); // 1280*720
```

Comment: it might be `this->size = textureDesc.Width * textureDesc.Height * 3/2 * sizeof(byte);` the correct size

Comment: Yes, NV12 is "1.5 bytes per pixel" on average. But be very careful about having 3/2 in your expression. 3/2 is an integer division and can evaluate to 0.

Comment: Using (w*h*3)/2 would be safer. Btw, sizeof(byte) is a bit redundant. It will always be 1, at least in this context.